# Suspicious traffic from my PC, want to investigate more

Tags: windows, networking, router, malware

I've been having issues with my IP getting blocked from certain websites by some CDN provider. I tried calling the website provider, my ISP and the CDN provider, with little luck, they kept saying it's not their problem.

I finally got to taking matters into my own hands, I installed wireshark on my desktop computer (which was the main suspect since if I wasn't using my PC for a few days my IP would be unblocked).

Indeed there was suspicious traffic going on, I turned off all internet devices in my house but the traffic was still there. My PC is the only one connected on the network but I get traffic from two IPs 192.168.100.11 which is my desktop, and 192.168.100.15 which is the cause of my problems. It seems the 15 IP keeps making traffic to weird ad websites, amazon compute and even that CDN that was blocking me, clearly not something a normal computer would do.

I don't know what to do from here, besides a windows reinstall, but that would wipe away everything, I'd like to track down how I got into this situation.

Running "ipconfig -all" doesn't show any device with the MAC that I blocked.

Doing a scan with "nmap" doesn't show anything either.

On the router, the name of the troublesome device was "securenat-xxxxxxxxxxxx" where the x's are its MAC address written without any separators.

For now, I blocked that IP's MAC address, it seems it's not smart enough to change its MAC and reconnect.

What to do from here?
Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: What is the MAC address you have xxx'ed out? With that we could maybe tell what kind of device is causing the problem.

Comment: Hi, the MAC is this one: DA:42:36:1A:66:14

Comment: Are you sure? No vendors have registered DA4236. This must be faked.

Comment: It would appear someone has hacked your router. Did you try a router full reset?

Comment: I'm sure that's the MAC, but are you sure it's the router that is hacked and not the PC? After having my PC offline for a few days the CDN unblocked my IP.

Comment: Why do you think your PC would have two IP addresses? In any case thew CDN will be blocking your router public IP address not your PC's private IP addesss.

Comment: My guess is a virtual adapter, but I've yet to find it. I wouldn't exclude your idea either.

Comment: It's more likely to be a wireless device connecting to your WiFi, but I suppose it could be a virtual adapter.

Comment: So ipconfig /all none of the information can be used to identify you

Comment: I disabled all wireless and there's only one physical computer connected to the router, there's also my ISP's modem which has some sort of public wifi integrated, but they say that's on a different network. Still, they don't care about my problem so I don't think I can get them to help.

Comment: "securenat-*" devices with MACs starting with DA: appear to be associated with VPN adapters. This should still be visible with "ipconfig /all" or in the Network and Sharing Center. See [this](http://www.overclock.net/t/1526339/please-help-me-identify-this-device) for more info. Do you have any VPN client software installed such as SoftEther?

Comment: I do, but the adapter is disabled.

Comment: Uninstalling SoftEther seems to have worked, thanks @CConard96